# Add conditionals to azure devops pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to add conditionals to this pipeline so that the trigger and pool will change depending on the branch.

looking for examples I saw that I could do something like this but I get syntax errors when executing the pipeline

```
variables:
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'develop') }}:
    branch_name: develop
  ${{ elseif eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'certification') }}:
    branch_name: certification
  ${{ elseif eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    branch_name: master

  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'develop') }}:
    pool_name: Pool_NCC_Develop
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'certification') }}:
    pool_name: Pool_NCC_Certification
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    pool_name: Pool_NCC_Master

trigger: 
  branches: 
    include: 
    - ${{variables.branch_name}} 
  paths: 
    include: 
    - app/* 

pool: ${{variables.pool_name}} 

resources: 
  repositories: 
  - repository: devops 
    type: git 
    name: devops 
    ref: master 

variables: 
- group: DevSecOps.POC 

steps: 
- checkout: self 
- checkout: devops 

- bash: mv devops/ ${BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME}/.scripts/ 
  displayName: dir 

- template: pipelines/template.yaml@devops
```

Is it possible add that conditions in the pipeline?

Comment: You don't specify whether you're using Azure DevOps Server (on-prem) or Azure DevOps Services (cloud). There's a limitation in Azure DevOps Server 2020 and below: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops-2020#conditional-insertion